# Как получить аватарку пользователя с сервера discord через python requests?

Tags: python, requests, discord

Нужно получить url аватарки, используя requests. Есть токен бота и ID сервера, ID пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = member.avatar_url
img_data = requests.get(url).content
with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

эта штука сохранит картинку в файл test.jpg